# How to add SPFx client side webpart to MasterPage

Tags: master-page, spfx, spfx-webparts, client-side-rendering

I have a webpart that is developed using SharePoint Framework. This wepart should appear across the pages in the site collection. I know that we can add server side webparts in master page. How can we add a client side(SPFx) webpart to masterpage?

Comment: are you able to add SPFx webpart or extenstion to master page? if yes then please post the answer as I'm looking for the same to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not add spfx webparts to masterpage. You can use spfx extensions for modern pages.